# Trying to git clone: How to unlock bitbucket account without solving CAPTCHA?

Tags: git, certificate, bitbucket, clone, captcha

I am trying to do a git clone of a repo but failed the authentication too many times when the Windows credential manager popped up (I probably inputted the wrong password) so now I'm getting the error:

> Your Bitbucket account has been locked. To unlock it and log in again
> you must solve a CAPTCHA. This is typically caused by too many
> attempts to login with an incorrect password. The account lock
> prevents your SCM client from accessing Bitbucket and its mirrors
> until it is solved, even if you enter your password correctly.
>
> If you are currently logged in to Bitbucket via a browser you may need
> to logout and then log back in in order to solve the CAPTCHA.

My organization uses some certificates that get auto loaded in the browser for authentification so when I log out and log back into bitbucket, there is no CAPTCHA but instead a popup that prompts me to select a certificate. Once I select the certificate, I am logged in without having to solve any CAPTCHA. However by skipping the CAPTCHA I can't "unlock" my account like the git clone error message was prompting me to. Any workaround for this?

Comment: You should able to clone using ssh. Or you can download the zip and use it. The captcha will have expiry and later that you should able to clone via http.

Comment: Navigate to Windows Credential Manager > Windows Credentials > git:https://your_name@bitbucket.org and click remove. Then try signing in again.